# Install with apt an old version of Node on Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: ubuntu, node.js

I'm getting crazy installing Node 16.x on Ubuntu.

I use

```
curl -fsSL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_16.x | sudo -E bash -
```

And then

```
sudo apt-get install -y nodejs
```

But the version installed is the 18.x

```
sudo apt list nodejs -a
```

Return me

```
nodejs/kinetic 18.7.0+dfsg-5ubuntu1 amd64
nodejs/unknown 16.18.1-deb-1nodesource1 amd64
```

How can I remove the first one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had problems with this as well. So there are many tutorials how to install different version of nodejs but they did not work in my case. However the last with nvm did.

**Method 1: Install nodejs from specific source**

```
cd ~
curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_16.x -o nodesource_setup.sh
```

by changing setup_16.x to your version, you change the version

```
sudo bash nodesource_setup.sh
```

then you test sources with

```
# sample on Ubuntu 22.10
$ cat /etc/apt/sources.list.d/nodesource.list
deb https://deb.nodesource.com/node_16.x focal main
deb-src https://deb.nodesource.com/node_16.x focal main
```

Then you install nodejs from that source (did not work in my case)

```
sudo apt -y install nodejs
```

And check installed version

```
node -v
```

This should return

```
v16.19.0
```

but in my case (Ubuntu 22.10) I got the new version

```
v18.7.0
```

**Method 2: Install Node Vesrion Manager or nvm**
This worked in my case:

```
sudo apt install curl 
curl https://raw.githubusercontent.com/creationix/nvm/master/install.sh | bash 
source ~/.bashrc
```

**Now to install an older version of nodejs with nvm**

you can first check available versions by

```
nvm list-remote
```

and then install specific version by (ex. version  v16.19.0)

```
nvm install 16.19.0
```

and check with:

```
$ node -v
v16.19.0
```

**To install latest version of node with nvm**

```
nvm install node 

$ node -v
v18.7.0
```

Hope this helps someone to